# All fields do not get displayed in the grid view

Tags: asp.net

I have written a query in mysql as follows:

```
   SELECT inquiry_id, event_name,MAX(ValueData1) as ValueData1
  ,MAX(ValueData2) as ValueData2
  ,MAX(ValueData3) as ValueData3
 ,MAX(ValueData4) as ValueData4
FROM
(
  SELECT  inquiry_id,event_id,event_name
  ,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 1 THEN CONCAT( Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS ValueData1
  ,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 2 THEN CONCAT( Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS ValueData2
  ,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 3 THEN CONCAT( Edition,' - ',sent_on) END AS ValueData3
 ,CASE WHEN mailer_id = 4 THEN  CONCAT( Edition,' - ',sent_on)  END AS ValueData4

  FROM crm_support_inquiry 
) AS crm_support_inquiry
GROUP BY inquiry_id,event_id,event_name
```

The output of which is as follows:
[image]

When i run the query and try to display the data in grid view i get only two fields in the output i.e. inquiry_id and event_name i.e. first two fields. Remaining fields are not getting displayed. What is to be done? i want full query output to be displayed in the grid view.

Comment: Your query does not return `event_id`. How could this field be displayed on the grid?

Comment: sorry i mean only first 2 fields get displayed i.e. inquiry_id and event_name